# Google sheet filter range if present in range 2

Tags: google-sheets

I have two ranges Absent days A2:A and Company holidays B2:B Need to bring the range of Absent days if it is not available in Company holidays.
How to achieve this in google sheets ?

```
Filter(A2:A, A2:A<>B2:B)
```

did not work. Or how to get does not match range

Answer (score 0):

```
FILTER(A2:A,ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0)))
```